# Ruby: Reading integers from file and put them into array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a file (`InputFile.txt`) containing blocks of integer numbers that each block is split using `*` character. Each block contains some rows that each row contains three integers, for example:

> 4 1233 8
>
> 2 55 11
>
> 2 4 33
>
> > *
>
> 3 5 34
>
> 2 1 44
>
> 6 5 33
>
> > *

I want to read each block and put the integers in each block in a 2D array and do some processing on it. I found the following code:

```
f = File.read 'InputFile.txt'
f.split('*').each  do |set|
  set.split.map(&:to_i)
```

This code can read each block, But I don't know how to put each block in 2D array. I tried for example `set[0][0]` and it returns 4, but when I tried set[0][1] it returns blank space. Can anyone tell me what should I do? I want to see `1233` as the second number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = File.read 'InputFile.txt'
data_array = f.split('*').map  do |block|    
    block.split(/\n+/)
    .map { |e| e.split(/\s+/)
    .map(&:to_i) }
    .reject { |a| a.empty? }
end
# => [[[4, 1233, 8], [2, 55, 11], [2, 4, 33]], 
#     [[3, 5, 34], [2, 1, 44], [6, 5, 33]]]
```

This will work for any number of `blocks` separated by `*`. And, in each block, `rows` are separated by any number of new lines, and in each row, the `integer` elements are separated by any number of white spaces.

As, each block is a `graph`, and, three elements in each `row` represents `source_node`, `dest_node` and `weight` respectively, so, to access these information, you can do the following:

```
data_array.each_with_index do |row, index|
    p "Graph: #{index}"
    row.each do |inner_row|
        p "source_node: #{inner_row[0]}, dest_node: #{inner_row[1]}, weight: #{inner_row[2]}"
    end
    p '- - -'
end

# => "Graph: 0"
# "source_node: 4, dest_node: 1233, weight: 8"
# "source_node: 2, dest_node: 55, weight: 11"
# "source_node: 2, dest_node: 4, weight: 33"
# "- - -"
# "Graph: 1"
# "source_node: 3, dest_node: 5, weight: 34"
# "source_node: 2, dest_node: 1, weight: 44"
# "source_node: 6, dest_node: 5, weight: 33"
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I access to each number? for example using block[0][0]?

Comment: You can just loop through the array and print the numbers. Could you please tell me what exactly you want to do with this?

Comment: I want to use each block as a graph which first number is first node, second number is second node and third number is the weight of the edge connecting two nodes, so I need to access each component.

Comment: @starrr please look at my updated answer and let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much :)

Comment: You are most welcome. Glad I could help. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 2):

If the file is not overly large you can just "gulp" it into a string, split on the asterisks (along with whitespace on each side), and then break up the pieces.

Let's first write some data to file:

```
str =<<-BITTER_END
4 1233 8
2 55 11

2 4 33
*
3 5 34

2 1 44
6 5 33
*
5 4 1
22 65 98
13 15 71
BITTER_END


FName = 'temp'
IO.write(FName, str) #=> 75
```

Now we read and process the file:

```
 IO.read(FName).
   split('*').
   map { |s| s.strip.split(/\n+/).map { |s| s.strip.split.map(&:to_i) } }
  #=> [[[4, 1233, 8], [2, 55, 11], [2, 4, 33]],
  #    [[3, 5, 34], [2, 1, 44], [6, 5, 33]],
  #    [[5, 4, 1], [22, 65, 98], [13, 15, 71]]]
```

Here's another to write that. It's more verbose, but it makes it self-documenting, facilitates debugging and testing, and improves maintainability:

```
class String
  def to_blocks(split_char)
    split(split_char)
  end

  def to_lines
    strip.split(/\n+/)
  end

  def to_arr_of_ints
    strip.split.map(&:to_i)
  end
end
```

Then:

```
IO.read(FName).to_blocks('*').map { |block|
  block.to_lines.map { |line|
    line.to_arr_of_ints } }
  #=> [[[4, 1233, 8], [2, 55, 11], [2, 4, 33]],
  #    [[3, 5, 34], [2, 1, 44], [6, 5, 33]],
  #    [[5, 4, 1], [22, 65, 98], [13, 15, 71]]]
```

If you'd prefer not to monkey-patch `String`, you could use [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), or just make one argument of each of the three methods a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
f.split("*").each do |block|
    result.push []

    block.split("\n").each do |line|
        result[-1].push line.split.map{ |i| i.to_i } unless line.split.size == 0
    end
end
```

Comment: Each block is to be an array of an array of integers, not an array of integers.

Answer (score 1):

Modified your code to add the nested array:

```
output = []

col = 0
row = 0

f = File.read 'InputFile.txt'
f.split('*').each do|set|
    output[row] = []
    set.split(' ').each do|item|
        output[row][col] = item
        col += 1
    end
    row +=1
    col = 0
end
print output
```

Result:

```
[["4", "1233", "8", "2", "55", "11", "2", "4", "33"], ["3", "5", "34", "2", "1", "44", "6", "5", "33"]]
```

Just make sure not to have a trailing * otherwise it will create an empty inner array.  Also wasn't sure if you wanted each new line of numbers in its own array or to read until the next astericks.  I assumed read until the astericks.

Comment: Each block is to be an array of an array of integers, not an array of integers.

Comment: The OP says the astericks defines the block, so each of those is a sub array within the main array.

Comment: Yes, but the OP said, "...put the integers in each block in a 2D array...". Incidentally, when you reply to a comment you should include the member's name (e.g., `@Cary`) so the member will be notified by SO that a message has been left.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  Guess we'll wait for OP to give more detail :)